# Simple way to convert an array of non-optionals to an array of optionals

Tags: arrays, swift

I wish to assign an array [T] to an optional array [T?]. This seems like it should be straightforward but the only solution I came up with is to do it manually.

```
struct ArrayHelper<T> {
 func toArrayOfOptionals(input: [T]) -> [T?] {
  var result = [T?]()
  for value in input {
      result.append(value)
  }
  return result
 }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like something `map` could do neatly for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there are any built-in ways to do this seamlessly, but map ought to be a simpler solution:

```
var input = [T]()
let output = input.map { Optional($0) }
```

**Edit:** Code modified based on suggestions in comments.

Comment: Slightly shorter: `let output: [Optional] = input.map { $0 }`

Comment: Or `let output = input.map { Optional($0) }`

Comment: Now I know that an Optional is just a type that decorates other types with a plain old init just like everyone else. Thanks!